# Future tense of 'drink': It will be drunk/drank/drunken?

Tags: future-tense, conjugations

Referring to a bottle of water, the sentence in question is: "I assure you, it will be drunk."

Is this correct?

Comment: I have a bottle of wine that must be consumed by 2022. Must the wine be "drunk" by 2022 ?

Answer (score 1):

The grammar is correct, but it sounds a little bit awkward to say it like that because when you say **drunk**, it brings to mind the image of a person who has been intoxicated with alcohol. Bottles don't get drunk, people do. You would more commonly hear it worded in another way to avoid the passive voice. Possibly, something like this:

> I assure you that someone will drink this bottle of water.

Answer (score 0):

The "future tense" of *drink* is *will drink*.

The "future tense" of *be drunk* is *will be drunk*.